# valgrind, on AMD x64, no useful stack info available

Tags: stack-trace, valgrind, memory-leak-detector

when use valgrind to check memory leaks, I encouter a very strange problem. 
On 32bit linux, the leak stack infos are very clear like:

```
    ==10650==    by 0x8130FD3: SFNTSetContactServer
    ==10650==    by 0x81106CA: CLibLicense::GetOneLicense(std::string&, void*&) 
    ==10650==    by 0x81108C2: CLibLicense::StartingGet(void*&) 
    ==10650==    by 0x810F01A: CLibLicense::GetLicense()
    ==10650==    by 0x810DEBB: CLicenseManager::DoGetLicense(void*, unsigned int)
```

But on x64 linux, I can only get **???** infos like this:

```
    ==31031== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 196 of 2,210
    ==31031==    at 0x4A0646F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
    ==31031==    by 0x46AF78: ??? (in /opt/usr/local/sbin/Server)
    ==31031==    by 0x46B016: ??? (in /opt/usr/local/sbin/Server)
    ==31031==    by 0x421F99: ??? (in /opt/usr/local/sbin/Server)
    ==31031==    by 0x42C240: ??? (in /opt/usr/local/sbin/Server)
    ==31031==    by 0x42D731: ??? (in /opt/usr/local/sbin/Server)
    ==31031==    by 0x42FC65: ??? (in /opt/usr/local/sbin/Server)
    ==31031==    by 0x465C01: ??? (in /opt/usr/local/sbin/Server)
    ==31031==    by 0x463DB6: ??? (in /opt/usr/local/sbin/Server)
    ==31031==    by 0x3116A1D993: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
```

The program doesn't use dlopen/dlclose as the valgrind FAQ said.

**update 1, add file stat infos**

```
    file Server
    Server: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

any comments are welcome!

Comment: Check `file /opt/usr/local/sbin/Server` to make sure the symbols were not stripped.

Comment: the file were not stripped. 
file Server Server: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

Comment: Are you using a current version of valgrind (3.6.1)?

Comment: The valgrind version 3.6.1, the latest version on its website. # valgrind --version
valgrind-3.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like you have stripped the symbols from your program.

Comment: The file is not stripped as the 'file' command shows. GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-23.el5) shows the info "Reading symbols from /opt/usr/local/sbin/Server...(no debugging symbols found)...done" while debug it. But gdb7.1(installed by myself) doesn't show that infos (Reading symbols from /opt/usr/local/sbin/Server...done.).